# When I use CE Image inside Gwcode categories, it's not parsed

Tags: ce-image, gwcode-categories

When I use Ce Image inside the Gwcode categories tags, it's not parsed.

```
{exp:gwcode_categories group_id="5" cat_id="{segment_3_category_id}" depth="1|2|3" custom_fields="yes" style="linear" orderby="cat_name" }

    {exp:ce_img:pair src="{cat_image}" width="300"}<img src="{made}"/>{/exp:ce_img:pair}

{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

It is a parser order priority problem??

Comment: Add parse="inward" to the gwcode parameters?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for your reply. It's working fine!! I already tried but it was not working, I guess because of the cache browser. So i gave up.... After you message i tried again, it's working :)

Comment: Your welcome, but i don't know how to accept the answer.... I can't see no button, option with accept answer.

Comment: i found the vote for useful comment ...

Comment: @JeremyDaalder you need to add your reply as an answer (in the big box below) instead of a comment, so Stéphane can accept it

Comment: Ah ok....using phone client for the first time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parse="inward" to the gwcode categories parameters.